# Notify user by email when matching content is uploaded

Tags: views, users, rules

I'm setting up a real estate website that sends an email to a user notifying them when a property meeting their specifications is uploaded.

Any ideas how I can do this in drupal 6/7 ?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [subscriptions](http://drupal.org/project/subscriptions) module also and especially at [this](http://atendesigngroup.com/blog/extending-subscriptions-module-node-reference-subscriptions) tutorial. I think this is a much simpler approach.

Comment: This is looking way better than my thoughts.

Answer (score 0):

Just speculation here, but I'd have a bunch of CCK/Fields and Taxonomies on your property content type.  Then I'd put those same fields/taxonomies on the User objects (in 7 you can do this directly, because users are fieldable, but in 6 you would use something like [Content Profile](http://drupal.org/project/content_profile))

Then you would hook into the saving/updating of your property content type (most likely using a combination of [hook_nodeapi](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--hooks--core.php/function/hook_nodeapi/6) in 6, [hook_node_insert](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--node--node.api.php/function/hook_node_insert/7) and [hook_node_update](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--node--node.api.php/function/hook_node_update/7) in 7 and hook_form_alter) to compare the fields/tags on the property to users with the same or similar tags/fields and then send those users an email.

If you have large number of users/properties, you'll probably want to use [hook_cron](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--hooks--core.php/function/hook_cron/6) to batch process the recently updated nodes instead of doing them on demand.  Also, you should be sure to store which properties a user has been notified of to avoid duplicates.